# ERR_NO_BUFFER_SPACE error on M1 Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, websocket, vite

I have been using the Macbook Pro M1 for web development for the past 7 months.

Lately, after about 1-2 minutes of starting my dev server (React with Vite and Gatsby), I get an ERR_NO_BUFFER_SPACE in Chrome, and I don't have an internet connection.

My co-workers with non-M1 Macbooks do not have the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me the error was produced by an Extension in VSCode, I had "Console Ninja" installed which attempts to grab console messages and errors and display them in line with the code. Once the extension was uninstalled everything went back to normal.

Comment: Same here! Same extension! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So looking for this error in Chromium we get a reference to ENOBUFS in the source code here:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/base/net_errors_posix.cc

According to this https://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-ENOBUFS the error is due to:

> In programming, ENOBUFS is a POSIX error code defined in . This condition caused by lack of memory in the OS`s buffers. Typically occurs in socket programming

I would suspect that there's a bug in the socket programming in Chrome that is mostly manifested in the ARM version of the operating system. This could either be a Chrome bug or an OS bug.

In this message https://groups.google.com/g/nodejs/c/ahVUQHRVhAo?pli=1 it suggests that it could be caused by excessive writes. Could something in your React code be overloading a network buffer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my angular projects, but after closing visual studio the connection came back to normality. I uninstalled some extensions such as ninja log, WSL, html to jsx, etc. I could work normal again. I'm also using M1 Macbook Pro. I hope this can help you.